# Update Hosts file in instance so they can communicate by the DN

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

Can anybody help with this task?I need to write ansible playbook to  update Hosts file in instance so they can communicate by the DN .Cant figure out how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than updating the hosts file on each server with Ansible, is it not possible that you could instead use a AWS [private hosted zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html) within Route 53.

If you use this method, ensure your VPC has the [following settings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html) enabled:

- Enable DNS support
- Enable DNS hostnames

By using this method rather than the hosts file, you can perform DNS changes outside of Ansible whilst keeping the records private.